# SQL calculate time diff in View

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I make function call in VIEW in order to calculate the difference between two time variables
What I have right now is

```
CREATE TABLE Recordings
(
    recording_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    start_time TIME,
    end_time TIME
)

CREATE VIEW duration(start_time, end_time)
    AS SELECT R.start_time, R.end_time
        #Function call to calculate time
    FROM Recordings R;
```

I looked up SQL documentation, it only has date_part which calculates the date difference, how do I calculate TIME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract the two values:

```
CREATE VIEW duration(start_time, end_time)
AS 
SELECT R.start_time, R.end_time,
       R.end_time - R.start_time as duration
FROM Recordings R;
```

The result is a value of type `interval`. If you want something else, there are plenty of examples on how to convert an interval to e.g. the number of minutes or seconds.

Answer (score -3):

As [documented on Sqlines](https://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff): `DATEDIFF(ss,start_time,end_time)`

Comment: Postgres doesn't have this function

Answer (score -4):

You can use timediff function as

```
timediff(R.end_time,R.start_time)
```

to calculate the time.

Comment: Postgres doesn't have this function